# SQL Query Phpmyadmin is not giving correct results having more than 3 tables with WHERE Clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am having relational database and trying to execute following query up to 3 tables It is giving me correct results i.e. 248 records of students in institute id 910, but when I try to make a query having more than 3 tables it gives me 19000+ results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student,StudentRegistration,RefStudentType,RefGender,SubjectCategory 
WHERE Student.student_id=StudentRegistration.student_student_id 
AND StudentRegistration.reg_student_type_std_type_id = RefStudentType.std_type_id 
AND Student.student_gender_gender_id = RefGender.gender_id 
AND StudentRegistration.reg_student_subjectCat_sub_cat_id=SubjectCategory.sub_cat_id 
AND Student.student_institute_inst_id=910;
```

`

Tried with JOIN as well but same 19000+ records incorrect results

`SELECT * FROM Student INNER JOIN StudentRegistration ON student_id=student_student_id INNER JOIN RefReligion ON RefReligion.religion_id=Student.student_religion_religion_id INNER JOIN RefStudentType ON RefStudentType.std_type_id=StudentRegistration.reg_student_type_std_type_id WHERE student_institute_inst_id=910;`

Any solution, query logical errors or something new

Comment: Start by replacing implicit joins with explicit joins and add representative sample data and desired outcome as text. NB joins are cumulative so one ore more of your tables must be a many to other tables one, probably the last table you added to the query.

Comment: [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) you really should have kicked by now

Comment: Joins will give me correct results but what is happening here I am not doing it wrong by the way

Comment: And why would 19000+ results not be correct? All depends on the relations you data has...

Comment: I have checked by removing one by one table whenever I have 3 tables it works fine

Comment: 19000 records actually exists in student table

Comment: I have tried with INNER JOIN as well, again 19000+ records

`SELECT * FROM Student INNER JOIN StudentRegistration ON student_id=student_student_id INNER JOIN RefReligion ON RefReligion.religion_id=Student.student_religion_religion_id INNER JOIN RefStudentType ON RefStudentType.std_type_id=StudentRegistration.reg_student_type_std_type_id WHERE student_institute_inst_id=910;`

Comment: This works fine 248 records
`SELECT * FROM Student INNER JOIN StudentRegistration ON student_id=student_student_id INNER JOIN RefReligion ON RefReligion.religion_id=Student.student_religion_religion_id  WHERE student_institute_inst_id=910;`

Comment: Please post your table schema and sample data.  A dbfiddle is best.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to having several records for one data. For example, there might be several records in the SubjectCategory table for id = '910'

It is best to use left/right/inner/outer joins without using from tbl1, tbl2

What I suggest is to check the tables one by one with the id.

Comment: I have checked it one by one with ids it shows 248 records with 3 tables when I add one extra table it gives 19000+ records. And Yes I have checked it with INNER JOIN as well. I don't know What I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Post the join query also. So we can check it.